# Object filter crashes if no results can be found

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsarray, nsobject

I have written some code to find a user's favourites out of an array of custom objects. It works absolutely fine unless that object does not exist, in which case it just crashes. I was considering completely rewriting the code a different way, but I imagine there is probably a way to fix it... I just can't figure out how.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideCell

    var ride = DataManager.sharedInstance.getRideByName(favouritesArray[indexPath.row] as! String)

    if ride != nil {
        cell.rideNameLabel.text = ride!.name

        var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        cell.updatedLabel.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(ride!.updated!)

        if ride!.waitTime! == "Closed" {
            cell.waitTimeLabel.text = ride!.waitTime!
        } else {
            cell.waitTimeLabel.text = "\(ride!.waitTime!)m"
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func getRideByName(name: String) -> Ride? {
    let result = self.rideArray.filter({
        $0.name == name
    })
    return result[0]
}
```

Like I say, it works fine if the Strings in favouritesArray can be found, however it crashes if not.

Can anyone suggest what changes I could make to stop the crash, and to just get it to return nil?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `result`'s length - you can do so by replacing

```
return result[0]
```

with

```
return result.count == 0 ? nil : result[0]
```

Comment: `return result.first` would be the swiftest way :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `first` property on the filtered array:

```
return result.first
```

which returns an optional. A better option, though, is to use the `indexOf()` function (if you're in Swift 2), as it doesn't build an entire array, and stops looking through the rest of the rideArray once it finds what you're looking for:

```
return self.rideArray.indexOf { $0.name == name }.map { self.rideArray[$0] }
```