# Return no cell based on nil variable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is a bit of a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440818/object-filter-crashes-if-no-results-can-be-found) question, but basically I am trying to figure out how I can return no cell if the result of a function is nil.

This is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideCell

    var ride = DataManager.sharedInstance.getRideByName(favouritesArray[indexPath.row] as! String)
    println(ride)

    if ride != nil {
        cell.rideNameLabel.text = ride!.name

        var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        cell.updatedLabel.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(ride!.updated!)

        if ride!.waitTime! == "Closed" {
            cell.waitTimeLabel.text = ride!.waitTime!
        } else {
            cell.waitTimeLabel.text = "\(ride!.waitTime!)m"
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

So at the moment everything works, however wherever `ride` does equal nil, I just get the prototype cell returned, whereas I would like it to return nothing.

I have tried hiding or changing the height of these cells to nil, but it just seems like messy solution. Anyone know a better one?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to return a cell for that method. Why don't you just change the value returned by numberOfRows?

Comment: why wait until `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to decide whether to return a cell or not,  why don't you proceed before passing the number of cells

Comment: @rocky I can't change the numberOfRows, because it displays the cells in the order that they have been favourited. So if you have favourited 4 things, but only two can be found at the at index 2 and 3, then changing the numberOfRows would display the two empty ones.

Comment: @user3746428 if you have an array of all items and you want to display just the favourited  items, just do the work with the array and then count it so you will get the correct number of cells

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that you **always** know how many **valid** rows do you have and you publish this number by implementing UITableViewDataSource's `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` method. So if at some moment number of rows changes you should call `UITableView.reloadData` not to try to hide excess rows.

To get an array of valid rides try something like:

```
var newArray:[String] = []
for str in favouritesArray where DataManager.sharedInstance.getRideByName(str!) != nil
{
    newArray += [str]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

determine the number of rows by implementing `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) {
    if section == 0 {
        return arrayName.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. As a few people mentioned, I had to figure out what to display before dealing with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Basically I added some code to figure out which favourites could be found in the array and put it in `viewWillAppear`.

```
    for index in 0...favouritesArray.count - 1 {
        var ride = DataManager.sharedInstance.getRideByName(favouritesArray[index] as! String)

        if ride != nil {
            favouritesFound.append(ride!.name!)
            println(favouritesFound)
        }
    }
```

Works perfectly now! Thanks everyone.